# Add two integer columns together, avoiding strings and Nan

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add two columns together that have `nans` and strings. I'm also trying to use more vectorization.

It works no problem, but my method just looks a bit messy.

I just don't like the look of the `try except`. That's the only way I could think of to avoid errors adding `strings` , `ints` and `nans` together. Is it normal to use try except in this way or is there a more pythonic way? Could this slow down my vectorization?

Here it is:

```
import pandas as pd

d = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,'string',4,pd.np.nan],
                 'col2':['string2',4,5,pd.np.nan,6,8]})
print(d)

     col1     col2
0       1  string2
1       2        4
2       3        5
3  string      NaN
4       4        6
5     NaN        8
```

Function to add the strings:

```
def addition(col1,col2):
    sums = []
    for num1, num2 in zip(col1,col2):
        try:
            sums.append(int(num1)+int(num2))
        except:
            sums.append(pd.np.nan)
    return sums

d['col3'] = addition(d.col1,d.col2)
```

And I got my expected output:

```
     col1     col2  col3
0       1  string2   NaN
1       2        4   6.0
2       3        5   8.0
3  string      NaN   NaN
4       4        6  10.0
5     NaN        8   NaN
```

My question is: is it normal to use `try except` like this? Is there a less `noob` way to avoid errors?

Comment: I would recommend your except statement only catch the TypeError exception, instead of a catch-all

Comment: I would recommend using `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'`

Answer (score 3):

Another way is to use [`pandas.to_numeric()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'`

```
d['col3'] = pd.to_numeric(d['col1'], errors='coerce') + \
            pd.to_numeric(d['col2'], errors='coerce')
print(d)
#     col1     col2  col3
#0       1  string2   NaN
#1       2        4   6.0
#2       3        5   8.0
#3  string      NaN   NaN
#4       4        6  10.0
#5     NaN        8   NaN
```

Essentially you try to convert each value to a numeric, and return `NaN` if there is an error.